# Jquery autoclose alert dont work properly

Tags: jquery

I tried to create a simple autoclose alert using Jquery, but have some problem.
The alert is automatically closing, but if you click continuously several times the alert is show/hide that much of times.
Whereas I want to replace the previous alert if button is clicked suddenly.
Here are my codes:

HTML

```
<button id="btn">Show Alert</button>
<table id="tbl">
<tr>
    <td width=200 height=200>
        <div id="alt"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="btncnt"></div>
        <div id="altcnt"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Script

```
$("#tbl").hide();
$("#alt").hide();
$("#btncnt").hide();
$("#altcnt").hide();

var btncount = 0;
var altcount = 0;
function autoclosealert(message){         
$('#alt').html(message)
.show(800)
.hide(800, function(){altcount+=1;});   

$('#btncnt').html("Btn Click: "+btncount);
$('#altcnt').html("Alt Count: "+altcount);
}
$("#btn").click(function(){
$("#tbl").show();
$("#btncnt").show();
$("#altcnt").show();
autoclosealert("Hello !!!"); 
btncount+=1;
});
```

CSS

```
#alt{
border: 1px solid grey;
background-color: blue;
padding: 20px;
}
```

This is my fiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/mitu/6mv18jms/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `stop()` on each click before adding any new animation to the queue to clear any previous ones:

```
$('#alt').html(message)
    .stop(true)
    .show(800)
    .hide(800, function () {
        altcount += 1;
    });
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6mv18jms/3/)

Comment: Thanks Rory McCrossan, its working now and meets my requirement.

Comment: Rory  can you tell me why the alert count is not increasing as hide()  finish executing?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `stop()` function to stop all previous animations.

```
$('#alt').html(message)
.stop(true)
.show(800)
.delay(2000)
.hide(800, function(){altcount+=1;});
```

In include delay () function if you need it.

http://jsfiddle.net/6mv18jms/5

Comment: Thanks Marcos Pérez Gude for your reply, but its not working. The alerts are still comming that much of times how much the button is clicked.

Comment: Yes, you only must to add true value to stop function. see the update

Answer (score 0):

Its good to disable the button until the animation is not completed, rather than queuing up the animations in successive fashion.

**JS CODE:**

```
function autoclosealert(message) {
$('#alt').html(message)
    .show(800)
    .hide(800, function () {
    altcount += 1;
    $('#btn').removeAttr('disabled'); //enable the button after animation is completed
});

$('#btncnt').html("Btn Click: " + btncount);
$('#altcnt').html("Alt Count: " + altcount);
}
$("#btn").click(function () {
  $('#btn').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //disable the button on click
  $("#tbl").show();
  $("#btncnt").show();
  $("#altcnt").show();
  autoclosealert("Hello !!!");
  btncount += 1;
});
```

**Live Demo @ JSFIDDLE:http://jsfiddle.net/6mv18jms/4/**

Comment: Thats correct but but here Button is an example, actually I'm creating dynamically generated list on click(), disabling these seems not user friendly

Comment: @mitu1234: hmmm , didnt expect that. is it possible to post that in the jsfiddle